# How to export HyperbolicPolyhedron as STL?

Tags: graphics3d, export, polyhedra

Here's the starting point (It's the Mathematica "Spikey 2" logo):

```
Graphics3D[HyperbolicPolyhedron["Dodecahedron", 1.3], Boxed -> False]
```

Here is the link to the MathWorld source for the `HyperbolicPolyhedron` function: 
[mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicDodecahedron.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicDodecahedron.html)

I am trying to export this as an STL file.

I have tried many approaches and done extensive googling. I can get an STL for `Polyhedron` objects, but not for the `Hyperbolic` version. I have investigated `GraphicComplex`, and much more. All attempts have led to error: "INSERTDATATYPE cannot be exported to STL format" - even though sometimes it's the same datatype as successfully exported polyhedra.

So, perhaps there's something "special" about hyperbolic polyhedra. How can I export them to STL?

Comment: Where is the code for `HyperbolicPolyhedron[]`? There is no way people can help you if you do not give them code that they can evaluate in their own computers.

Comment: Hi JM,

Thx for the prompt reply.

The code is in my OP. Perhaps you can't see it? Included as code block. Here it is as simple text...

Graphics3D[HyperbolicPolyhedron["Dodecahedron", 1.3], Boxed -> False]

Hope that gets thru and helps...

Swami

Comment: And, here's link to Wolfram/MathWorld source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicDodecahedron.html.

Comment: You should have included the information that you got the function from MathWorld in your question; you gave no indication whatsoever that [you were not using a built-in function](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=HyperbolicPolyhedron).

Comment: Sorry for any confusion/shortcoming on my part. The code from MathWorld executed in my version of Mathematica, 11.2.0.0. I attempted 'Export["foo.stl",obj]', where 'obj' is the return value from the several variations I attempted.

OK, hopefully there's enough to go on, now...

Comment: Thx for any help you might be able to provide...

Comment: If not a built-in function, then perhaps it's embedded in the nb?

Comment: MORE DETAILS:

- When initially opened, `Graphics3D[HyperbolicPolyhedron["Dodecahedron", 1.3], Boxed -> False]` outputs graphic of the polyhedron.
- But, when evaluated subsequently, an empty red box is output.
- Furthermore, hovering over box gives msg: "HyperbolicPolyhedron is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive".
- This certainly gets at why export fails.
- Hm? Continuing to research/fiddle...

Comment: FOUND NOTEBOOK OUTLINING/DETAILING CONSTRUCTION OF OBJECT!:)

"Making the Escher-style hyperbolic dodecahedron symbolizing Mathematica 5"

https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5700/

- Deciphering, and attempting to evaluate in Mathematica v11.

- Encountering problems:(

- Notebook appears to evaluate upon opening, but when individual lines are re-evaluated errors occur:(

- Have managed to update some of the code, but still have long way to go...